# Filter CSV data from 2 days ago to 15 days later

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In order not to filter very old data, I was able to adjust the import perfectly ... But the file has data as of May 2020, has no value to me and weighs the spreadsheet a lot.

I'd like to limit this import to data only until 15 days from now. The rest do not need.

What do I have to add in the script so that it can make this future filter? Thanks in advance

```
function FiveThirtyEight() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Import CSV Data'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  var url = "https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches.csv";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;
  var now = new Date();
  now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  var values = csv.filter(function(e, i) {
    var temp = new Date(e[0]);
    temp.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return i > 0 && temp.getTime() >= yesterday;
  });
  values.unshift(csv[0]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Import CSV Data!H:J').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('0.00%');
}
```

Comment: I believe right now it loads the active sheet with data from yesterday and today.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

I found several problems with your current code. For one thing your filter was not working because it wasn't calculating temp date.  I think the dashes were causing problems for the Date() constructor.  Anyway I made several changes to it and now you can see the date range clearly by looking at the declarations for `daysAgo` and `daysLater`.  They have a -2 and +15 at the near the end of each line and they control your timespan for data relative to the current date.

You no longer have to unshift() the end header line because I skipped over in the filter loop.  The filter keeps a row if the return is true and it removes a row if the return is false.

Also you needn't use activate() at all.  I think it's a remnant of users that started learning their code from macros.

```
function FiveThirtyEight() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Import CSV Data');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getMaxRows(), sh.getMaxColumns());
  rg.clear({contentsOnly:true});
  var url="https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-api/club/spi_matches.csv";
  var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvA=Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  var now=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate());
  var daysAgo=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate()-2);
  var daysLater=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate()+15);
  var values=csvA.filter(function(e, i) {
    if(i>0) {
    var tA=e[0].split('-');//split on dashes to get FullYear,month and date
    var temp=new Date(tA[0],tA[1],tA[2]);
    return temp.getTime() >= daysAgo.getTime() && temp.getTime()<=daysLater.getTime();//this keeps data within the desired date range
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  sh.getRange('Import CSV Data!H:J').setNumberFormat('0.00%');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, I will do the tests now!