# Filtering .csv data before import (app script)

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that imports data from a .csv file daily. The .csv is pretty big (>20k rows), and it causes a huge load on the spreadsheet and sometimes results in script timeout.

I figured out that I don`t actually need all the 20+k rows but only those with date value in Column I > 2020-09-01. I tried several options with building in the filter in my script with no luck.
I would highly appreciate any help or guidance on how to filter the .csv data by column prior to importing it to a spreadsheet.

The script I`m using:

```
  function importOP() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("OP_Data_Daily.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),'\t');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('OP');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data to try to reproduce it? Also, have you checked similar posts like [Filter CSV data from 2 days ago to 15 days later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014078/filter-csv-data-from-2-days-ago-to-15-days-later) or [Filter CVS before importing to Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256412/filter-cvs-before-importing-to-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: @Kessy, sure! please find a sample .csv datasheet via the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kbodKC6-WraJ7-bCGQDlHrWQhYSjgOX920sWq0iGQpE/edit?usp=sharing

I did check the two posts you mentioned but hose solutions didn`t work for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, I think...

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),'\t')
  .filter(function(row, i){
    return i===0 || parseInt(row[8].split('-').join(''))>20200901
  });
```

Basically, it applies a [`filter()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) to the 2D array returned by `parseCsv()`. The filter uses a function to return only: the first row from the csv (the headers row) plus any row where the value of the 9th item (parsed as integer after removing all -) is greater than 20200901.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer yet. Just a note.

I think you imported your csv data with wrong setting.

Your [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kbodKC6-WraJ7-bCGQDlHrWQhYSjgOX920sWq0iGQpE/edit#gid=2001211328) looks like this:

[image]

But I believe it should look like this:

[image]

Since a default separator is comma `,`. But a separator in your data is a semi-colon `;`. You need to indicate it explicitly during import:

[image]

If you made the table with the script in OP you need to change this line:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),'\t');
```

with this

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),';');
```

But this is not an answer. Not yet. You still need a script that will crop your data.

**Update**

I just tried to make filter via simply script on your full csv date and it works more or less. It freezes a bit, but works.

Here is the my script:

```
function importOP() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("OP_Data_Daily.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),';');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('OP');
  sheet.clear();
  try { sheet.getFilter().remove() } catch(e) {}
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  var filter = sheet.getFilter() || sheet.getRange('I1:I').createFilter();
  var date = new Date("2020-09-01");
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateAfter(date).build();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(9, criteria);
}
```

[image]

**Update 2**

Okay, if you insist to paste filtered data in the table you can do it pretty easy this way:

```
function importOP_filtered() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("OP_Data_Daily.csv").next();
  var date = new Date("2022-09-01");
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),';');

  csvData = csvData.filter(row => new Date(row[8]) > date); // <-- here is the filter

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('OP');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Comment: ugh, sorry. Something went wrong when I created the sample datasheet - corrected it now. I created it manually, so the initial Utilities.parseCsv configuration is ok here - data is tab-separated in the .csv file

Comment: @Kate, see my Update

Comment: thanks, @Yuri! As I can see, the script you suggested copies all the data from .csv to a spreadsheet and then filters it. Unfortunately, that`s not what I need... I am looking for a solution that will filter out the unnecessary data (with finish date prior to 2020-09-01) **before** pasting the data to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Kate, see my Update 2